# PHP - How to replace $arg with textfile.txt content

Tags: php, arrays, arguments

I have a .txt file on my web server (locally) and wish to use that .txt content in my PHP block. The .txt file contains a number that is updated by another script on another page, but for this page I just want to pull the number/txt file contents from the file and need to replace with "**$savedSession**" on this function;

```
 $images->initFromSavedSession(**$savedSession**);
```

I can *echo* .txt content with *file_get_contents* function but just needed to using file content on that php function.

How can I do this?

Thanks so much for replies.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks for reply. I can access and echo content, but i don't know how to assigning it to a variable. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: @chris85 Thank you so much for cleverly and simply solition :)

Comment: Okay, posted that as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `echoing` you can use the `=` [assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) to assign the value to a variable.

```
$variable = file_get_contents('stuff');
```